# How to assign freestyle attributes to different objects for rendering?

Tags: rendering, freestyle

I have a quadrilateral mesh and a triangle mesh in my collection, for quadrilaterial we want to render the visible edge, for triangle mesh we want to render the whole boundary which included the occluded boundary. How to achieve this?

Thank you  very much!

The first picture represents the result which we render for triangle mesh,
and the second picture represents the results which we render for quadrilateral mesh.

Comment: You can use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to add pictures to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no  'in camera' discriminator between your Line-Sets, you *may* have to render them into different View Layers, and combine the layers in the Compositor.

But you can probably just link the meshes into distinct collections, and associate each Line-Set, (along with its style and its edge-selection method), with those collections:

[image]

It would depend on your case. Maybe you can illustrate it.

[image]

Comment: It works well, thank you very much!